# Trying to sign up for cloud identity free is forcing to sign up for 14-day free trial of G-Suite premium

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

I have a domain registered with Google Domains. I was trying to sign up for the Cloud Identity free version but some how I ended up into 14-day free trial of G-Suite premium. Even if I abandon that flow and restart with a different session, I end up in the G-Suite registration process. Is there a way to not sign up for G-Suite and only use the rest of the GCP?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're referring to using Custom Domains on Google Cloud Platform (GCP), or wanting to start a free trial on GCP to be able to use all the other Apps [2].
Additionally I found that Cloud identity is for free , as declared in the Cloud IAM Document [3]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#before_you_begin
[2] https://cloud.google.com/free/
[3]https://cloud.google.com/iam/pricing

Comment: I think Google uses admin.google.com accounts to setup admin accounts for both G-Suite and GCP. I first registered my domain with Google Domains. Then some how I ended up with the G-Suite flow which took an email address associated with the domain and is trying to setup as admin. But to complete that flow, I have to sign up for the 14-day trial. I want to only use GCP. When I try the GCP Cloud Identity free version it also ends up in this G-Suite flow. I even get emails that my 14-day trial is going to end on some date. Got bounced between 3 GCP support groups but no one could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I resolved my issue. As it's all trial-and-error I am not sure what worked and why. Just some observations if someone else runs into this situation.

1. I waited for more than 14 days, the trial period for G-Suite
   premium which the system some how thought I needed to complete.
2. As part of signing up for Cloud Identity, it no longer redirected
   me. However, it didn't accept the email I wanted to use (which I
   already used for the GCP account) saying that it's a personal
   account.
3. So I ended up using another email with my domain and
   that allowed me to complete the Cloud Identity registration. As part
   of this I completed domain verification.
4. After this, there is an
   option to "Rename User" which includes changing the email. I used
   this to change the email back to the one I wanted and it got
   accepted without any issues!
5. After this I tried to login and the
   system recognized that there is a personal and a business account
   and which one I wanted to signin to. I used business account and
   made sure everything was working.
6. I also noticed that the GCP
   account I originally had got under the organization (can be verified
   by looking for "this account is managed by ..." when you click on
   the profile.
7. At this point I went ahead and deleted the
   unnecessary personal account associated with my business email.

Everything seems to be working and as expected (except why a youtube redirect is needed when doing a sign-in for enterprise services?)

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to sign up for Free version.
When I tried to do it via G Suite console (Billing-> New services) it only allowed me to sign up for the Premium.
When I tried using a link from GCP, it said that my domain is already in use by another Google service.

So, how I made it working:

1. I went back to G Suite -> Billing -> New service
2. Sign up for Cloud Identity Premium
3. Came back to the Billing page scroll down and clicked on "Cloud Identity Free"
4. Signed up for it
5. On the Billing page cancelled the subscription to the Premium

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7389973?hl=en) to sign-up for Cloud Identity free (today) and was not prompted for GSuite free trial nor when I went to the billing section, under my active subscriptions, I did not see a GSuite free trial sub.

Since you already verified your domain and did the sign up, you can go to [admin console](https://admin.google.com), then go to the billing section and look for the subscriptions that you're currently using which should be GSuite premium (trail) and Cloud Identity free. Remove GSuite subscription and just stick with Cloud Identity. If you're not able to view this Cloud Identity free subscription, then take a look at the following [doc](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7668760?hl=en) to understand how to "Upgrade or downgrade Cloud Identity".

Even though you sign up for Cloud Identity, it still uses the admin console which is considered "GSuite console", here you can create/manage your users,groups etc. for your domain/organization (GCP).

Comment: The problem I have is that it's not letting me to get to the admin console. Right after login, it redirects me to complete the gsuite premium trial. There is no option to skip it.

Comment: What part of GSuite premium trial is it asking to complete? If it's asking to verify your domain and all of those steps this is default steps, this is done by default since the domain is verified and managed by the admin console, then based off of that an organization is created within GCP but keep in mind this org is created when you create your first project signed in to GCP as your new GSuite/Cloud Identity user example: siva@my-domain.com. Provide more info on what steps are the ones you can't skip.

Comment: I get a screen which says "Review your payment plan. Try G Suite free for 14 days." The next screen asks for credit card info.

Comment: So you haven't verified your domain then? If not; then just follow the guide that I provided in my response and follow those steps, it will only sign you up for Cloud Identity. Just create another personal gmail account temporary just for the sign up process. This is because that account that you used for this sign up (GSuite Free trial) may already be link to that process.